# SSL Connectivity from neo4j-java-driver 1.6.3

Tags: java, ssl, neo4j, openssl

I am a brand new user of Neo4J DB. I need to connect to the DB from my Java project. I am using **neo4j-java-driver 1.6.3** for the same. I am using **neo4j-enterprise edition 3.4.9** (installed via Debian repository in Ubuntu 16.04 ).

I have managed to established the no-authentication connection and basic authentication connection. I am facing issue while connecting a **SSL** enabled server. I am trying to connect through the below code:

> Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(url, AuthTokens.basic(username, password), Config.build()
> .withTrustStrategy(Config.TrustStrategy.trustCustomCertificateSignedBy(certFile)).toConfig());

I am getting the following error:

> **sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found**

How can I create necessary cert file here? I am new to SSL certificates too.

My neo4j.conf file looks like below:

> dbms.directories.data=/var/lib/neo4j/data
> dbms.directories.plugins=/var/lib/neo4j/plugins
> dbms.directories.certificates=/var/lib/neo4j/certificates
> dbms.directories.logs=/var/log/neo4j
> dbms.directories.lib=/usr/share/neo4j/lib
> dbms.directories.run=/var/run/neo4j
> dbms.directories.metrics=/var/lib/neo4j/metrics
>
> dbms.directories.import=/var/lib/neo4j/import
>
> dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512m dbms.memory.heap.max_size=512m
>
> dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
> dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=X.X.X.X
>
> dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
> dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
> dbms.connector.http.enabled=true dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
>
> bolt.ssl_policy=bigd
>
> dbms.ssl.policy.bigd.base_directory=/var/lib/neo4j/certificates/bigd
> dbms.ssl.policy.bigd.private_key=/var/lib/neo4j/certificates/bigd/private.key
> dbms.ssl.policy.bigd.public_certificate=/var/lib/neo4j/certificates/bigd/public.crt
>
> dbms.ssl.policy.bigd.client_auth=require

private.key and public.crt I have created as below:

> *sudo openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out neo4j.csr -keyout private.key sudo openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in neo4j.csr -CA*
>
> *ca.cert -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out public.crt*

I have created certFile specified in the java code as follows:

> *sudo openssl genrsa -out neo4j-client.key 2048 sudo openssl req -new -out neo4j-client.csr -key neo4j-client.key -subj "/CN=10.0.1.67/O=example.com" sudo openssl x509 -req -in*
>
> *neo4j-client.csr -CA ca.cert -CAkey ca.key -CAserial ./ca.srl -out*
>
> *neo4j-client.crt -days 3650*

I think I might be missing some configuration or I am not creating the certificates properly. How can I find out what I am missing?